# Adding a class to an element on a different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an html page foo.html and bar.html.

I want a button/link on foo.html to add a class to a div on bar.html. What is the javascript or jQuery to do this?

/foo.html

```
<a id="view1" onclick="addClass()" class="btn">View details »</a>
```

/bar.html

```
<div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse"><div>
```

/foo.js

```
function addClass() {
    ???
}
```

**EDIT:**

I can use whatever, as long as redirecting to a different page sets the class of a div.

Comment: Do you mean that the two pages are open simultaneously in two separate browser windows or tabs?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, you wouldn't be able to use Javascript for this. In order to transfer data between two different pages, you'll need to use some sort of server-side scripting. EDIT - Cookies might be a solution...

Comment: I think you could do this with a heartbeat script that checks a cookie

Comment: So, basically, no. I have to use another framework like knockout... k, thanks.

Comment: This is possibly an ["XY" problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), in which you're trying to do something that isn't necessary or can be done a better/easier way. However, there's not enough detail available in your question to understand exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson has the right idea, many ways to pick up on data from another page.  You could set a cookie, update the link to bar.html by adding a query string or a hash, bar.html?class=className or bar.html#className.

Comment: @RizBaltazar knockout won't help either...

Comment: or... you could use node.js and socket.io, and set up a room for each user based on an uuid, and then send a message from the client on page1 that triggers a message to page2 that is viewed by that user and change the class, but why on earth would you need such a thing. Rethink whatever it is you're doing, there's probably a better solution.

Comment: Would Knockout MVC help?

Comment: Umm, so he needs knockout right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can use cookies, localStorage, or postMessage to comunicate between pages but there is no way to direct access DOM of other page.

try this: check every Xms if localStorage has changed (well ugly solution but will work without server-side scripting ;) )

foo.js (attach it in both documents):

```
// apply to /foo.html
function addClass() {// toggleClass to be exact
  // set localStorage['collapse'] to 1 or 0 
  localStorage['collapse'] = localStorage['collapse'] ? 0 : 1;
}
// apply to /bar.html
(function() {
  var element = $('#collapseThree');
  if(element.length) {
    setInterval(function() {
      // when localStorage['collapse'] is 1, add class .collapse
      // other way: remove class collapse
      element.toggleClass('collapse', !!(localStorage['collapse'] || 0));
    }, 500);
  }
})();
```

You can do it smarter and replace setInterval with window.onfocus, it depends on your needs

Answer (score 1):

Javascript lives within a single page and can't affect anything on another page directly.

Instead, change the link on the first page to be like so:

```
<a href="view1#foo" class="btn">View details »</a>
```

Then use js on the receiving page to parse the URL, prevent default action, and add a class if the anchor is present in the URL.

Something like this (I don't do js/jquery, so someone else can improve this for you):

```
var wHash = window.location.hash.split('#')[1];
if (wHash) {
    $('#foo').addClass('whatever');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use socket.io to do this, have client A emit an event that invokes the addClass method on other clients.